# PostgreSQL Group By A, but still pull B field

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, pivot

I have table look like this:

```
rpt_date   | shipping_id | total_usage 
--------------------------------------
2013-11-01 | 1           | 10
2013-11-01 | 2           | 2
2013-11-01 | 3           | 5
2013-11-02 | 1           | 15
2013-11-02 | 4           | 1
2013-11-03 | 1           | 20
2013-11-03 | 2           | 3
```

And I want to use single query to get the result like this:

```
rpt_date   | 1 (shipping _id) | 2 (shipping_id) | 3 (shipping_id) | 4 (shipping_id)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2013-11-01 | 10 (total_usage) | 2               | 5               | 0
2013-11-02 | 15               | 0               | 0               | 1
2013-11-03 | 20               | 3               | 0               | 0
```

How should I query this? I am trying to query like this

```
SELECT 
  rpt_date,
  CASE WHEN shipping_id = 1 THEN total_usage ELSE 0 END AS a,
  CASE WHEN shipping_id = 2 THEN total_usage ELSE 0 END AS b,
  CASE WHEN shipping_id = 3 THEN total_usage ELSE 0 END AS c,
  CASE WHEN shipping_id = 4 THEN total_usage ELSE 0 END AS d
FROM 
  Table A
WHERE 
  DATE(rpt_date) BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-03' 
GROUP BY 
  rpt_date 
ORDER BY 
  rpt_date
```

Above query gimme error that `shipping_id` and `total_usage` must be part of `GROUP BY`. What is the issue with my query?

Comment: It gives that because it doesn't know what to do about total_usage, its not "clear". You told it to group by something, but not what to do with the other. Why are you even grouping? you aren't doing anything with it (no grouping function)

Comment: Total_usage is being set but never used - Why bother?

Comment: yeah I know my query is wrong. My point is how can I use single query to get the result as I mentioned above? May be you have other method to query to get result like above? Your help is really appreciate.. tq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with SUM:

```
SELECT 
  rpt_date,
  SUM(CASE WHEN shipping_id = 1 THEN total_usage ELSE 0 END) AS a,
  SUM(CASE WHEN shipping_id = 2 THEN total_usage ELSE 0 END) AS b,
  SUM(CASE WHEN shipping_id = 3 THEN total_usage ELSE 0 END) AS c,
  SUM(CASE WHEN shipping_id = 4 THEN total_usage ELSE 0 END) AS d
FROM TableA
WHERE DATE(rpt_date) BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-03' 
GROUP BY rpt_date 
ORDER BY rpt_date
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/efc18/2)</kbd>

You are grouping by rpt_date, but not telling it what should happen to the other columns. This way you get the SUM of total_usage for those dates. If you only have one record, for each date and each shipping_id it will return only that value.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is close. One way to get this pivot result is like this:

```
SELECT 
  rpt_date,
  MAX(CASE WHEN shipping_id = 1 THEN total_usage ELSE 0 END) AS a,
  MAX(CASE WHEN shipping_id = 2 THEN total_usage ELSE 0 END) AS b,
  MAX(CASE WHEN shipping_id = 3 THEN total_usage ELSE 0 END) AS c,
  MAX(CASE WHEN shipping_id = 4 THEN total_usage ELSE 0 END) AS d
FROM 
  Table A
WHERE 
  rpt_date BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-03' 
GROUP BY 
  rpt_date 
ORDER BY 
  rpt_date ;
```

Comment: tq it works too, i rather use SUM than MAX... tq very much bro :)

Comment: Yes, I should add that my query works on the assumption there is a unique constraint on `(rpt_date, shipping_id)`. With `SUM()` it should work even if there isn't.